# Java 7 Runtime Shutdown Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Java 7 runtime support was deprecated on December 13, 2017, and will be shut down entirely on January 16, 2019. It is replaced by the Java 8 Runtime Environment.
=> I want to ask java 7 will be shut down entirely on January 16, 2019 is to stop technical support or not to run on java 8 environment

Comment: You should be asking Google Support, not here.

Comment: @NobitaGpDeDust, I see that you are new to SO, welcome. I proposed an answer, if it solved you issue, consider [accept/upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so other people who may have the same question can see it works. Again, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7):

> January 16, 2019  All remaining Java 7 projects are updated permanently to Java 8, and the Java 7 runtime is permanently disabled.

If you want to migrate to Java 8, follow this link [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8).